# How can I post request json body in swift using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I need to make a POST request in the json body for my app backend but the response returns a failure. I assume my json formatting or encoding is wrong but I can't figure out what the problem is. I have attempted a lot of different solutions but I haven't been able to find one that works. Can anyone see which part of my code is responsible for the failure?

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": self.authValue,
    "x-iyzi-rnd": self.randomString,
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
]


let parameters: [String: Any] = [


        "price": "1.0",
        "paidPrice": "1.1",
        "paymentChannel": "mobile_ios",
        "paymentCard": [
            "cardHolderName": "card_name",
            "cardNumber": "card_no",
            "expireYear": "2030",
            "expireMonth": "09",
            "cvc": "123"
        ],
        "buyer": [
            "id": "123123123",
            "name": "john",
            "surname": "doe",
            "identityNumber": "12345678902",
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "registrationAddress": "nidakulegöztepemerdivenköymahborasokno1",
            "city": "istanbul",
            "country": "turkey",
            "ip": "192.168.1.82"
        ],
        "shippingAddress": [
            "address": "nidakulegöztepemerdivenköymahborasokno1",
            "contactName": "janedoe",
            "city": "istanbul",
            "country": "turkey"
        ],
        "billingAddress": [
            "address": "nidakulegöztepemerdivenköymahborasokno1",
            "contactName": "janedoe",
            "city": "istanbul",
            "country": "turkey"
        ],
        "basketItems": [
            [
                "id": "321",
                "price": "0.3",
                "name": "binocular",
                "category1": "collectibles",
                "itemType": "physical"
            ],
            [
                "id": "432",
                "price": "0.5",
                "name": "gamecode",
                "category1": "game",
                "itemType": "virtual"
            ],
            [
                "id": "543",
                "price": "0.2",
                "name": "usb",
                "category1": "electronics",
                "itemType": "physical"
            ]
        ],
        "currency": "try"


]


Alamofire.request("https://api.iyzipay.com/payment/auth", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in response

    let jsonResponse = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
    print(jsonResponse)



})
```

Is there any different way to post request json body?

Comment: Try to not modify `Accept`, `Content-Type` and `Cache-control` headers, let Alamofire decide those. Just send `Authorization` and everything else you need. Pretty sure, also, the headers for authorization are always capitalized.

Comment: Try with POSTMAN first and then check.

Comment: @Aditya I already tried that its gave same error.

Comment: @AlejandroIván when I erase some headers response says invalid signature.

Comment: Did you try with Postman and the same headers? If it gives you the same error, it's a backend issue and not a frontend one.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Yes I tried with same headers and its gave same error.

Comment: If you are using same headers and parameters and Error is same on the Postman too. Then it can be the error in the backend. Also try to confirm with backend that what exact values are required in parameters and in which format.

Comment: @Aditya I also control parameters again and again I can't find any problem about that. Is my code seem correct or not?

Comment: Your code seems correct. Make your backend work with Postman first and, when that happens, come back to your front end code.

Comment: @makeser What exact error are you getting?

Comment: @KrishnaKantKaira I get invalid request. It says json will be wrong.

Comment: @makeser JSON looks perfectly fine. You must be missing some mandatory param. Ask the backend developer if you are missing some param in body or header.

Comment: @makeser are you using third party iyzipay ? make sure you are sending all the required parameters listed: https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/checkout-form/initialize#request. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KrishnaKantKaira I don't wanna use checkout form. I want to take only payment like in here https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/api/auth

Comment: @KrishnaKantKaira I check parameters in that link again and again but I can't see any wrong parameter...

Comment: @makeser JSON seems perfectly fine. Please check if you are getting any listed error code, otherwise i would suggest to connect with their dev team, there is a 'get in touch with us' option at the bottom.