# How can I make request with nested json objects in swift with alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have nested json to request the server. I already try a lot of ways to do that but response gave me an invalid request. It is probably according to the wrong json. How can I get the correct json for request? I already check again and again my parameters and these are all correct. In basket_items node, is a json array so conflict will be in there I assume. Can you help me? I already try that 4 days. 
Here my code :

```
let payment_card: JSON = [
    "cardHolderName": "card name",
    "cardNumber": "card number",
    "expireYear": "2028",
    "expireMonth": "09",
    "cvc": "123"
    ]

let buyer: JSON = [
    "id": "mak123",
    "name": "john",
    "surname": "doe",
    "identityNumber": "1234567890123",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "registrationAddress": "mehpare sokak",
    "city": "Istanbul",
    "country": "Turkey",
    "ip": "192.168.1.82"
]

let shipping_adress: JSON = [
    "address": "mehpare sokak",
    "contactName": "jane doe",
    "city": "Istanbul",
    "country": "Turkey"
]

let basket_items: JSON = [
    [
        "id": "321",
        "price": "0.3",
        "name": "binocular",
        "category1": "collectibles",
        "itemType": "physical"
    ],
    [
        "id": "432",
        "price": "0.5",
        "name": "gamecode",
        "category1": "game",
        "itemType": "virtual"
    ],
    [
        "id": "543",
        "price": "0.2",
        "name": "usb",
        "category1": "electronics",
        "itemType": "physical"
    ]

]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": self.authValue,
    "x-iyzi-rnd": self.randomString,
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
]


let parameters: Parameters = [

        "locale": "tr",
        "conversationId": "123456789",
        "price": "1.0",
        "paidPrice": "1.0",
        "installment": 1,
        "paymentChannel": "MOBILE_IOS",
        "basketId": "12345",
        "paymentGroup": "OTHER",
        "paymentCard": payment_card.rawValue,
        "buyer": buyer.rawValue,
        "shippingAddress": shipping_adress.rawValue,
        "billingAddress": shipping_adress.rawValue,
        "basketItems": basket_items,
        "currency": "TRY"


    ]






Alamofire.request("https://api.iyzipay.com/payment/auth", method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
            print ("return as JSON using swiftyJson is: \(swiftyJson)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print ("error: \(error)")
        }

}
```

How can I manage that json? Is my fault in basket_items or where?

Comment: "response gave me an invalid request" - so is this a server issue?

Comment: @koen I already talked backend developer, he said json format will be wrong.

Comment: How is this question different from the one you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931849/how-can-i-post-request-json-body-in-swift-using-alamofire ?

Comment: Don't repost questions. It's clearly a problem with the server communication so only the owner of the service can answer the question.